# Converting a KML file into a shapefile as applied (vector to raster)

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, vector, kml

I have received a KML file from a drone, this file displays the path at which the drone was flown. I would like to convert this into a shapefile to display the swaths that the drone covered. I know how to add in the attributes and such but is there a script to convert the KML to shapefile easier?

[image]

Comment: Use QGIS export to convert KML to shapefile, it won't though create a raster if the input KML is vector data.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Your Q. title states "*(vector to raster)*" but you ask about converting to shapefile. Shapefiles are vectors. Do you want to convert to raster or to shapefile?